# Does anyone backup SQL Databases >= 4Tb instead of replication?

Tags: database-backup

So the question is in subject.

Backing up SQL database is very time consuming procedure.

How anyone make backups for such huge SQL databases?

I'm not about specific instruments but "architecture" of such thing.

Answer (score 0):

First, (online) replication is not a backup *at all*, as many things you want a backup to protect you from would be immediately replicated out to your "backup". Accidentally dropped a table or messed up a `DELETE` statement? Yeah, the data is gone in the replica too...

That said, you have multiple options to consider, e.g.

- In slow changing DBs, a regular file backup might just be acceptable.
- Backing up transaction logs and running those against a full backup for restore
- Standby replication / log shipping
- Block based backups of modern file systems and storage hardware, e.g. ZFS snapshots with ZFS send/receive
- Other methods your particular DB software might offer
- A combination of some of the above

What you end up with will largely depend on your specific situation.